# How to call function more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code I am trying to implement that calls a function

```
<body>
    <nav id="menu">
        <div id="app">
            <ul class="List">
                <li><span>Enter Number below</span></li>
                <div id="coachid">
                    <input type="text" name="coachid" id="textbox1" value="22984">
                </div>              
                <li><span>Fitness Programs</span>
                    <ul id="programs">
                        <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li><span>10-Minute Trainer</span>
                            <ul id="10min">
                                <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                <li><span>Base</span>
                                    <ul id="10minBase">
                                        <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                        <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="basic" id="basic" value="10MinTrainer"/>
                                        <button id="getWebSite">Open Website</button><br/>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><span>Deluxe</span>
                                    <ul id="10min">
                                        <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="basic1" id="basic1" value="TMT"/>
                                        <button id="getWebSite">Open Website</button><br/>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><span>Deluxe</span>
                                    <ul id="Deluxe">
                                        <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li><input type="hidden" name="basic3" id="basic3" value="TMTUpgrade"/>
                                        <button id="getWebSite">Open Website</button><br/>
                                    <ul>
                                </li>                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </li>
                <ul>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

and here is the function

```
$(function() {              
    $('#getWebSite').unbind().click(function(){               
        goUrl = 'http://www.example.com/' + $("#basic").val() + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val();
        window.location = goUrl;       
    });             
});
```

I am trying to call the function multiple times throughout the code to redirect the button to a site based on info held within the html. Is this possible?

Comment: You have repeating ID's in your HTML...that's *bad*

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you please explain more?

Comment: how do I make it so that it will call same function without using same id?

Comment: Put different ID's to your buttons.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: Better still, use class selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your function, apply a class to those elements that should have the click handler, and create the click function:

```
<button class="myClass">

$(function () {
    function doSomething() {
        goUrl = 'http://www.example.com/' 
          + $("#basic").val() 
          + '?referringRepId=' 
          + $("#textbox1").val();

        window.location = goUrl;
    }

    $('.myClass').unbind().click(function () {
        doSomething();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good point! The `#basic`, `#textbox` would also have to be use classes. Then the code in the function can pick the relevant `input` element.

Comment: Yeah, I was sticking to the fundamental question of calling the function. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why would you need to name the function?

Comment: How else would you call it? You could leave it in the click function, but this is better from a best practice standpoint.

Comment: how would the corresponding html look like to call the function?

Comment: Whenever possible, JS belongs outside your HTML. This alone does the job.

Comment: I've added a button tag to my answer in case that clears it up.